# Share DVD drive over wifi (or lan)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, network-shares, dvd

I have two laptops win 8 and win 7. Win 8 has no dvd drive. I want to backup the os and drivers of win 8 using the dvd writer of win 7. Both systems are connected to a wifi router over which I have no control. I can also connect them to a lan network. I tried the instructions on a website and it did not work - http://www.howtogeek.com/114254/how-to-share-cd-dvd-drives-over-the-network-on-windows/

I also tried to use paragon netburner software for this and that also did not help. Is there a simple way to get this done ? Win 8 backup menu allows dvds, but not sure if it allows me to use a network dvd drive.

Comment: I don't have direct experience with the setup you want. Depending on the type of DVD backup you want to do, a network DVD drive (if it is possible) may time out during a write due to the extra potential latency. Maybe you can create a backup to the local computer, then use something like DropBox to keep a backup on the second computer?

Comment: @SunWKim - My dell backup tool allows only usb drive and dvd.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that it is not possible to share a DVD drive **including the burning capabilities**. The link you posted refers to a way to share it as a folder, not as a DVD Burning unit.

My suggestion would be to burn ISO images and then burn them on Win 7:

- On Win 8, backup the files to an ISO image.
- Copy the image to Win 7 and burn it into a DVD.

Comment: How do I back it up as an ISO image ? My dell backup tool (in win 8) only allows external USB or Discs. Does win 8 os allow backup as ISO ?

Comment: There are many free tools (although I'm not up to date with Win 8 compatibility) to burn DVD discs that can also burn into ISO images. For instance **ImgBurn** and **InfraRecorder**.

Comment: Thanks. But those software are useful when you want to just burn some files into ISO. Windows backup or dell backup tool will not let me back it into ISO form. I just remembered that there are some DVD drive emulation tools which let you run an ISO image off your harddisk as if it was a real DVD. Is there some software to trick windows backup or dell backup into putting the backup to a virtual drive software which will write it as an ISO. Then, I can simply copy the ISO to cloud or 8gb thumb drive and paste it in my win 7 laptop. I prefer not to spend $35 on a external DVD writer.

Comment: There are virtual DVD drives that also let you mount virtual DVD images that are writeable. I think this is what you want... http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/totalmounter-free-virtual-cddvd-burner-thats-easy-use.htm -- Some caveats as there is no mention of Windows 8 compatibility. You also want to do a dry run where you back it up to the virtual image, back it up to the cloud, down it from the download, restore the image, and see if the entire process is reliable. Good luck!